# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No Symbols have been loaded for this document in VS2013 and MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I have MVC application built in VS 2013. it was working all fine, suddenly i could not debug the javascript file from IE10.

**Problem :**

The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

I have placed breakpoints in javascript files and those are not firing.

After googling i tried various settings as below

1. Run Visual STudio in Administrator mode.
2. Clear browser Cache.
3. Run the application in Debug Mode.

Still the issue persists. Am i missing something please suggest.

Comment: Please can you post the full error message?  I ask because there are various reasons why this can happen such as that the version has changed since your last build etc

Comment: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document. 
This was the error message i saw few days back. Strangely once i restarted the machine its working now. :( Thanks for ur time Coulton

Comment: Weird stuff like this happens sometimes and a reboot of closing down of visual studio does the trick.  I've been in that position myself.  Glad its sorted now